# Duplicate objects in RLMArray one-To-Many Relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a problem without my realm db. I have these objects:

```
// Person.h
@interface Person : RLMObject
//... property declarations
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end

// Dog.h
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSInteger id;
@property NSString *name;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Dog) // Defines an RLMArray<Dog> type 

// Dog.m
@implementation Dog
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}
@end
```

And when I make this i will get 2 the same objects in Person.dogs

```
Person *jim = [[Person alloc] init];
Dog *rex = [[Dog alloc] init];
rex.id = 1;
rex.name = @"Rex";

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:jim];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[jim.dogs addObject:rex];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[jim.dogs addObject:rex];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

What i should do that after this i will have only one object with unique primary key? I understand that RLMArray just an array, but early i think that realm realize something that one-to-many relationship have only unique objects.

Here are a screenshots from a Realm browser and Xcode debug area

[image: Realm browser]
[image: Xcode debug area]

here are 3 dogs, because a run my code 3 times, but it doesn't matter, and i can make dogs with my Id but it doesn't matter in this case

[image: custom ids]

Answer (score 3):

`RLMArray` has array semantics. It doesn't behave like a set, which holds only unique objects. That means you can add the same object multiple times. If you want to have only one object of each type in the end, you should add only one object of each.

The output of the debugger you posted indicates that you run your app 3 times, but the dog had a different id each time, so they are threated as different objects.

If you would use `[Person createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:jim];`, where `jim` is either an `NSDictionary` or a standalone object with just one dog and the id of the dog and the person equals to the ids persisted in your Realm, then you would end up with still having just one person and one dog and all their remaining attributes will have updated values.

Comment: @maruis dog id had no effect in this case. because i can save one dog 2 times with the same ids. I added a screenshot above.

Comment: Now i had one dog in the dogs table, but 2 or more dogs in dogs relationship.

Comment: You end up having the dogs multiple times in the relationship, because you add them multiple times. If you don't want to add them more than once, then you would need to check whether it's already added and add it only if it's not there yet.

Comment: I agree with @marius, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @marius i understand that, but i don't want check it by myself, Core Data+magical record can make this automatically. Because i need to check all properties in objects and then if i have a difference i should replace it.

Comment: About last paragraph: If so many person exists in a Realm and if those persons have so many different dogs and if these dogs and persons update so frequently(think it like channel-messages relationship), then it becomes a performance degrading implementation. Why isn't there anything like RLMSet in Realm which would take care of these operations implicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't persist anything yet.

If you persist RLMObjects with the same primary key, realm will throw an exception (because of the primary key).

```
// Update or create jim with with the dogs
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[Person createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:jim];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

// Or add Jim with the dogs to Realm with transaction
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:jim];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

**Edit:** I agree with **Marius**, if you first persist the dogs separately and then after that add it to a Person (one-to-many) you wouldn't have a problem anymore, because realm would throw an exception in the first place when persisting the dogs separately.

Comment: Nope, this is not working. I forgot add this lines of code in my question

Comment: @NosovPavel are you sure the dogs are persisted? Did you verify this in the Realm browser ?

Comment: Yes, now you can see a screenshots at the end of my question.

Comment: @NosovPavel I'm using a different type for ID, not NSInteger but the primitive type "long". Maybe it goes wrong there..

Comment: this is not worked. Because in the documentation written NSInteger.

Comment: @NosovPavel I want to add a working example for you, but I'm a bit busy right now.

Comment: you are wrong, realm does not throw an exception :-)